# IE issue: Title of child window is being set as "#" on hash change

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, location

In my application we are using `location.hash` for navigation. We are also setting the title of document dynamically on page load. but when ever we changing the hash value of location title is getting reset to "#".

Note: Once we are get information from hash, we are removing hash string from location leaving  only url + "#".

Comment: I'm afraid that the CIA confiscated my mind-reading helmet and I don't have a TV camera pointed at your computer any more.  We need to see a **minimal** code example.